# Python udp logging only original message

Tags: python, logging, udp

I have implemented an udp logger in my python project.
It works fine as long as I receive the messages with my server and do not output the first four bytes.

I have no access to the server that is to receive messages in the future and cannot cut anything off or change the message there.

Is it possible to send messages in Python via udp that only contain my original message?

Here is my code for the logger:

```
logger = logging.getLogger('main_logger')
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
handler_udp = DatagramHandler(settings.LOGGING_UDP_HOST, settings.LOGGING_UDP_PORT)
formatter_udp = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
handler_udp.setFormatter(formatter_udp)
logger.addHandler(handler_udp)
```

For example, this is what a message looks like at the server if I can't cut anything off:

```
b'\x00\x00\x02-}q\x00(X\x04\x00\x00\x00nameq\x01X\x0b\x00\x00\x00main_loggerq\x02X\x03\x00\x00\x00msgq\x03X\x19\x00\x00\x00startup q\x04X\x04\x00\x00\x00argsq\x05NX\t\x00\x00\x00levelnameq\x06X\x04\x00\x00\x00INFOq\x07X\x07\x00\x00\x00levelnoq\x08K\x14X\x08\x00\x00\x00pathnameq\tX;\x00\x00\x00/home/app.pyq\nX\x08\x00\x00\x00filenameq\x0bX\x06\x00\x00\x00app.pyq\x0cX'
```

This is how it looks right when I receive it with my server:

```
{'name': 'main_logger', 'msg': '', 'args': None, 'levelname': 'INFO', 'levelno': 20, 'pathname': '/home/app.py', 'filename': 'app.py'}
```

Thanks

Comment: The DatagramHandler uses `pickle` to serialize the message. You can unpickle it or overwrite `makePickle()` to get a different serialization.

Comment: If you have no access to the server that is to receive messages in the future, how do you know how it will interpret what you send it? What is it expecting to be sent?

Comment: @Klaus D. Thank you for pointing this out. I was then able to find the following question and solve my problem: [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61056701/python-sockethandler-with-plain-text)